# How can we find index path in table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How to find the index path of table view. I want to delete a row using an id(some data), that id is added as object in my mutable array of table view. Now I have my custom method that will do the deletion functionalities, How to get index path so that I can do deletion operation?

TIA .

Comment: post some code dude. I think you will use swipe to delete of tableView

Comment: post some code ..... and be more clear about your question.

Comment: If it is swipe then there is no probe, I can get index path. But I want to call my custom method from another view. That view I will have only id information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you mean correct?:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

If not, please elaborate more on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please see my above comment for more clarification.

Comment: So pretty much you just need to pass the index path to another view correct?

Comment: I can't get view1's table information in view2, so I have only data. With that data I have to find row, and delete.

Comment: I think I understand. You have your own deletion method in another view than your UITableview but you need the indexPath in order to do it properly. So in your commitEditingStyle method, just pass the value to your other view and call the method. Unless I am missing something else here.

Comment: my own method is there in table view class only, Input for that method is only id, To delete any row from table view I need Index path, that I am not able to get using my id (data). From swipe deletion I can get index path, but I'm having delete button specific for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry I am still not understanding. Post more code in your original question so we can visually understand whats going on.

Comment: You don't need indexpath for deleting rows. You should update your model, that storing data, then do [table reloadData]; Put to tag property of your button index of object in data array.